# I'm looking for a stand alone fantasy with a lesbian protagonist sent as ambassador to different culture

Tags: story-identification

The author is female also and I remember something about birth names being determined by crystals. And the main character is assigned a servant to help her.

I'm pretty sure it was before 2010; I know that doesn't narrow it down much. I'm pretty sure the author was female and was from somewhere other than the U.S. There was, of course, the usual citywide struggle against the dark (evil) and the maid was actually pivotal to that and also was a thief. Unless I'm confusing more than one book, which is possible. I do know that the main character and the maid/servant end up sleeping together. That's the first indication you have that the main character is lesbian. This is bothering me more than I can say; I usually remember book titles and authors and the fact that this one has slipped from my memory doesn't mean it wasn't a good book because it was.

And it was a medieval type world.

It was not in a future US world or post apocalyptic version of modern society. It was in a completely different world with different countries and cultures, i.e.: Middle Earth. There was little, if any,technology. There was some kind of serious confrontation (good vs evil, light vs dark kind of thing) that the main character and her appointed servant ended up resolving.

And the book you are talking about Song of the Skylark is not it. There was absolutely no science fiction type references at all and it had nothing to do with homosexuals being driven off to any place years earlier. The homosexual relationship between the character and the assigned servant was incidental and not pivotal to the plot at all.

I apologize that I didn't make that clearer before now.

Comment: Do you have any idea when it was written, at least to the nearest decade? Novel, short story, graphic novel, or some other media? Any other details you can remember would help as well. There's actually quite a lot of LGBT oriented SFF.

Comment: “I'm looking for a stand alone fantasy with a lesbian protagonist sent as ambassador to different culture” Aren’t we all!

Comment: @Lorelynne: Was it set in a medieval type of world, more-or-less contemporary, or in the future?

Comment: I'm thinking of the somewhat dreadful "The Song Of The Skylark" Plot outline- In the mid 21st Century, the US is disrupted by tow events; the discovery of the gene complex that indicates homosexuality and  a collapse of the San Andreas faultline that separates California into an island.  The government sends all gays into exile on the island for a generation. After 70 years, all the gays are removed from mainland US, "therefore" it becomes a violent and backwards second-world nation, while the island has become like Scandinavia. An ambassador sent to US falls in love with the POTUS daughter ;/

Comment: This sounds a little like something by Ursula K. Le Guin.  Her "Hainish" novels and stories have in the background an advanced interstellar civilization that sends ambassadors to less advanced planets.  The story usually takes place within the context of the less advanced culture, so you don't see much technology.  The culture often has its own unique aspects in gender and sexuality, which are sometimes a major plot element, sometimes just an aside.  I don't recognize a particular work, but it might be somewhere to look.